# error ValueError: I/O can't write to a closed file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I wrote this piece of code basically it creates a txt file with today date and start logging to it, i made a function to save the file send it somewhere (email) reopen the file to continue writing to it,
Problem : i can't reopen it from inside the function please take a look and suggest a solution thanks in advance

```
import os, time
import datetime, pytz

x = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
i = x + datetime.timedelta(hours=3)
y = i.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%I:%M%P")
d = i.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
filename = d + ".txt" #name the file with today date
print(y) # print date and time at script start

l = open(filename, "a") #create the file

print("""
 """ + y, file=l) #log today date to the file

def sendf():
    print("test1", file=l) #test write
    clsfile = l.close() #save file before sending
    print("file saved now sending")                                           
    #code to send file to somewhere
    h = open(filename, "a") #open the file to write again                       
    h = l #if i open the file and assinged it to l directly  i get print("t>
          #UnboundLocalError: local variable 'l' referenced before assignme>

sendf() #function to send the file

print("write test", file = l) #test writing to the file

#error print("write test", file = l) #test writing to the file
#ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `global` to assign to a global from within a function.

```
def sendf():
    global l
    print("test1", file=l) #test write
    clsfile = l.close() #save file before sending
    print("file saved now sending")                                           
    #code to send file to somewhere
    h = open(filename, "a") #open the file to write again                       
    l = h
```